# Filter result of ListObjects on Amazon S3

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, model-view-controller

I have an Amazon S3 Bucket, my goal is to get the items filtered by keyName, has anyone got any idea on how to do this? 
At the moment I display all the contents from the bucket but it's not the best practice performance-wise, since I have 8k results.

To display the items I use the classic ListObjects method, at the moment my request is the following:

```
        var request = new ListObjectsV2Request()
        { 
            BucketName = bucketName,
        };
```

My idea is to use the "Prefix" parameter to filter the keys.
My keys are formatted like this:

```
        .../date_hour_name_itemid
```

An example might be

```
        .../250112_123456_JohnDoe_42
```

where 250112 means 25 of January 2012 and 123456 means 12:34:56

Let's say i have these items in my bucket:

```
      .../250112_123456_JohnDoe_42
      .../260112_123456_JohnDoe_42
      .../270112_123456_JohnDoe_42
```

I need to get the item with key that begins with 260112, the output will then be:

```
      .../260112_123456_JohnDoe_42
```

Thank you everyone, have a nice day!

Comment: If you specify `Prefix` in the parameters you can filter for keys that start with the given prefix.

Comment: @theduck can you provide me an example that works in my contest?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the items filtered by keyName"? Can you provide an example of what you actually want to do?

Comment: okay @JohnRotenstein let me edit the question

Comment: For your example simply set `Prefix` to 260112.

Comment: @theduck wow, is that as simple as it gets? Completely figured it out wrongly, thank you

Comment: Please note that the `Prefix` starts from the root of the bucket, so it will also need to include all the stuff before `260112`, such as `folder1/260112`.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `Prefix` parameter in your call to only bring back objects with a keyname starting with the prefix:

```
var request = new ListObjectsV2Request()
{ 
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Prefix = "260112"
};
```

Comment: okay, let's suppose that i have something before that date like

./A/260112 AND ./B/260112

I need to get both results

Comment: I believe you can only do that with multiple queries - one with `Prefix` set to `A/260112` and another with `Prefix` set to `B/260112`. If you are able to re-arrange the way the data is stored in S3 you might be better of with your keys starting with the date so that you can achieve this in a single query.

Comment: solved by adding a simple campaign selector. Users must surely know what they are looking forward :))))